# Android Geofence Trigger Delay/Failure

Tags: android, xamarin.android, geofencing, android-geofence

I've registered Geofences in my Android App for 5-6 locations.

The Geofence event I want, is Geofence Dwell with loitering delay of 10 sec.

But using this, the event is sometimes triggered in some Android devices, and doesn't trigger at all in others.

So, just for testing purpose, I considered below listed scenarios:

1) I reduced the loitering delay to 3 sec. This time results were better, it triggered in 4 out of 5 devices.

2) Another testing scenario was, I registered Geofence Enter event (which obviously has no loitering delay), and this time it triggered in all the devices.

Ideally, I need the Geofence Dwell event to be triggered with delay of 10 sec, because I don't to entertain frequent Geofence notifications on Enter event.

Please suggest what could be possibly wrong with Geofence Dwell with longer delays.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for testing purposes - you can try to test on different devices with Google Maps on foreground. In that case you would be able to know whether the problem lies in geofencing itself or in location services.

Comment: Agree with pkuszwski. My quick thinking would be that the location is so inaccurate and your geofence so small, that the position jumps outside of it during the 5sec period. How large geofences are you using? Also, are you testing on the foreground or in the background? I've discovered there are huge difference between different android devices' ability to detect geofences while in the sleeping mode.

Answer (score 3):

Typical Reasons for dwell trigger delays:

1. Location Adapter should be on and set to High Accuracy mode (from 
   System settings)
2. For dwell to occur, the mobile phone should be in transit i.e moving (if it's connected to charging, or usb, android recognises it as not moving and delays the location calculations )
3. Battery optimisation should be off (Triggers will be dealyed if it's on).
4. Try manually triggering Google Maps, or Ola/Uber, etc apps which force the device to get accurate location update. If such apps are in foreground, triggers are faster and more accurate.

If you requirement, is as small as a difference of mere 10 seconds of dwell, you might as well run your own timer logic on a background thread; since in the real world, how much distance in meters (which you specify as the geofence radius) is the device going to really travel in 10 sec ?

Comment: Some phones enable Battery Optimization for all apps by default. This bit me!